# How to find new Block and Filter app in windows 10 mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, call-sms-filter

After I updated my Lumia 640 to Windows 10 **Call + SMS filter** app was removed and should have been replaced by new **Block and Filter** feature. But I'm not able to find it on my phone. I'we already looked in **settings**, **applications** and on app **Store**, it isn't there. But it is, actually, listed in *Settings -> Privacy -> Background apps*. So, in theory, it is running but I can't open it's user interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To open Block and Filter go to `Settings->Extras->Block and Filter`.If this is not working for you, **there is a workaround** as described [here](http://www.wpxbox.com/how-to-block-calls-messages-on-windows-10-mobile/),

> However, due to some weird reason the app keeps crashing on my phone,
>   when opened through Extras. So, I found out another way to open the
>   app, tap on Phone> Click the three dots below> Click on Blocked calls.

Here are the step by step instructions,

1. Open the phone app, click on the three dots.

[image]

2. Click on the blocked calls.

[image]

3. Click on the hamburger menu to navigate in the Block and Filter app.

[image: menu in block and filter app]

You can also block and unblock calls without navigating into the app. Refer this [article](http://www.wpxbox.com/how-to-block-calls-messages-on-windows-10-mobile/) for details.

Comment: Before any of these ideas work you have to go to the setting to select Apps for Blocking Calls" and select Block and Filter. Until you do this call blocking options are all hidden.

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest you another way 
go to **Phone App** click **options(...)** button it will show options click **Blocked Calls** and you are there.