# How to automatically reject all calls from private numbers?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, calls, lumia-640-xl, call-sms-filter

I don't want to receive any call from private numbers and I want them automatically rejected. How would I do that on Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12946/106

Comment: By private numbers do you mean an induvidual number or a caller id restricted number?

Comment: caller ID restricted number.