# How can I block a caller on Lumia 521?

Tags: 8.1, call-sms-filter

I don't see a "block call" option when I press and hold number in history. The choices are "details", "delete" and "add to speed dial". I'm using a Lumia 521 and WP 8.1.

Comment: This question may already have an answer here [How to find new Block and Filter app in windows 10 mobile?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12946/how-to-find-new-block-and-filter-app-in-windows-10-mobile)

Answer (score 4):

For enabling block number you have to go to **Settings** > **Call +SMS filter** 
Here you can turn ON or OFF call blocking as well as manage blocked numbers and use some advanced settings.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Note that Call+SMS Filter is actually an app; it should be pre-installed on Lumias but if it isn't (or doesn't work) you can find it in the Store and install/update it.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/callsmsfilter/9wzdncrfj3jf?rtc=1 That is the link for the Call+SMS Filter App